# Laravel model event with multiple parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have currently implemented an event that gets fired when a model gets created:

```php
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'created' => EvaluationRequestForZ0UQ0::class
];
```

Nothing special, it works fine. But I would like to invoke the event on model creation with multiple parameters. Something like that:

```php
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'created' => event(new EvaluationRequestForZ0UQ0(User $param1, Job $param2))
];
```

How could I achieve that? Maybe my approach is wrong. If so, feel free to tell me another approach.

Comment: This article may be helpful https://laravel-news.com/laravel-model-events-getting-started

Comment: You could just raise a custom event as part of the handling of the `created` event. As far as I know since `created` is a built-in eloquent event you can't pass custom parameters to it since you're not the one who's raising it.

Comment: Many thanks for the additional information and illustration of the limitations.